# Is it possible to set up a VPN between two routers in the same house with different external IP addresses?

Tags: router, vpn, steam, network-discovery

I recently moved so South Korea. My house has ethernet jacks in each room, but each jack pulls a dedicated external IP address from the ISP -- for instance, I don't *need* any routers in order to access the internet.

At first I thought this was an awesome feature from this ISP, but turns out that this breaks network discovery between devices in the house for obvious reasons.

I do have a router in my office where my gaming computer is, and a router in my living room. What I'd like to do is make it so that devices like a [Steam Link](http://store.steampowered.com/app/353380/Steam_Link/) in the living room can discover my gaming computer in my office. I was thinking that perhaps a VPN between the two networks would be a correct approach, but I'm not sure if my terminology is correct, or if this network topology would solve this problem.

How can I achieve network discovery between these two networks given I have two Netgear routers (Netgear Nighthawk R7000 in office, Netgear R6300 in living room).

Comment: While that's basically the _purpose_ of a VPN, my initial guess is that Steam Link discovery will make it a pain in the ass...

Comment: If that's the case (being the purpose of a VPN) I'm more interested in getting an answer around how to actually setup a VPN between two home routers that have different external IPs than knowing if Steam Link will work with it out of the box. I'm not afraid to jump through some hoops for configuration.

Comment: You have the option to not use multiple exits and just use one of them, and then set up a wired or wireless network inside your house.  Or keep the multiple exits and create a wired/wireless internal network.  It would take some setting up but would eliminate the need for the VPN overhead and trying to get steam link across it.

Comment: I do not have that option. The only way I could make that  work is by running cable from room to room. I cannot control the exits at the jack's in any of the rooms. Things are a little different in South Korea -- the ISP was directly involved with the building of this house apparently. Also the overhead is minimal, were talking 4ms from each other IP addresses in this house.